# How do I correctly combine these AJAX and jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whenever I click this button:

```
<a onclick="AddToWishList(@item.id)" id="swapHeart" class="btn btn-default swap">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></span>
</a>
```

I want the button to change state with jQuery whenever the AJAX function is called

**AJAX:**

```
<script>
    function AddToWishList(item_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                itm_id: item_id
            },
            url: "/WishList/AddToWishList",
            success: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            error: function () {
                return "error";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#swapHeart').on('click', function () {
            var $el = $(this),
                textNode = this.lastChild;
            $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-heart glyphicon-heart-empty');
            $el.toggleClass('swap');
        });
    });
</script>
```

So my first thought was that I had to combine these two function together as one function. But how? Because the button first handles the AJAX function and after that the jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you want. If you want the AJAX to fire when you click the button, move it into the `function() { ... }` you have below. Otherwise, if you want the state to change when `AddToWishList` is called, then move that code into the `AddToWishList` function.

Comment: BTW, `e.preventDefault();` should be outside of `success`. you can add that as the first line of the click event handler

Comment: @Shyju Whenever the `e.preventDefault()` was on the beginning, the ajax call wouldn't work. Whenever it was in the `succes`, it would work..

Comment: @TylerRoper I want the state of the button to be changed whenever the AddToWishList is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `onclick` and pass the item id to a data attribute.

```
<a id="swapHeart" data-item_id="@item.id" .... </a>
```

Then do everything inside the jQuery click handler

```
$('#swapHeart').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();// calling this in success of ajax is too late
  var $el = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      itm_id: $el.data('item_id')// from data attribute
    },
    url: "/WishList/AddToWishList",
    success: function(data) {
      // do something with or based on response data

      $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-heart glyphicon-heart-empty');
      $el.toggleClass('swap');
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("ajax error");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This way the console is not logging an ajax error, but the ajax and jquery functions are both not working now like this for me..

Comment: OK. I saw your image and you have more than one of these. Instead of `id="swapHeart"` make `swapHeart` a class and change the above selector to `$('.swapHeart')`. Also are you loading those elements using ajax? If so change to  `$(document).on('click','.swapHeart', function(e){`

Comment: These elements are not using ajax. Changing all the things you said didn't do it.

Comment: Can you log something inside this clcik hndler and not in ajax to see if event is working? Any errors in browser console? Note I removed the `jQuery(function ($) {` just for simplicity

Comment: There are some errors in the browser console, but they don't have to do with this I think https://imgur.com/a/IHbDDq9

Comment: Oh yes...that `$ is undefined` is a big one and will break things. Have to get rid of that one

Comment: I fixed that problem, because I didn't reference the jquery script above the script like this: `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>` but it's still not doing anything or giving me any console errors..

Comment: No idea why. Not much has changed from the way you originally had it and said it worked. What I wrote is really straightforward click handler stuff. Try `console.log($('.swapHeart').length)` before `$('.swapHeart').click`. Shouldn't be zero